# Sphinx with metaphone and wildcard search

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx, metaphone

we are an anatomy platform and use sphinx for our search. We want to make our search more fuzzier and started to use metaphone to correct spelling mistakes. It finds for example `phalanges` even though the search word is `falanges`.

That's good but we want more. We want that the user could type in `falange` or even `falang` and we still find `phalanges`. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

If you are interested you can checkout our sphinx config file [here](https://gist.github.com/joker-777/74d39f731b1b49ad5ac5).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well you can enable both `metaphone` and `min_prefix_len` on an index at once. It will sort of work.

```
falange*
```

might then just work. (to match `phalanges`)

The problem is the 'stripped' letters may change the 'sound' of the word (because change the pronunciation)

eg falange becomes `FLNJ`, but falang acully becomes `FLNK` - so they no longer 'substrings' of one another. (ie phalanges becomes `FLNJS`, which `FLNK*` wont match)

---

... to be honest I dont know a good solution. You could perhaps get better results, if was to apply stemming, BEFORE metaphone. (so the endings that change the pronouncation of the words are removed.

Alas Sphinx can't do this. If you enable stemming and metaphone together, only ONE of the processors will ever fire.

---

Two possible solutions, implement stemming outside of sphinx (or maybe with regexp_filter. Not sure if say a porter stemmer can be implemnented purely with regular expressions)

or modify sphinx, so that ALL morphology processors apply. (rather than just the first one that changes the word)

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for you long answer. We have already tried `min_prefix_len` but didn't achieve the desired result. It somehow even disables the function of `metaphone`. I'm gonna play around with the stemmer to see what kind of result I will get with it but as you said, I can only enable either `metaphone` or a stemmer. Using it outside of Sphinx or even modify Sphinx looks quite tricky. Is this such rare use case? I don't understand why there isn't a better more straight forward solution.

Comment: ok, maybe was mistaken about how the two interplay. In my experience its pretty rare, only the second time seen something like this discussed. Do see the very last sentance of http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2014/11/26/sphinx-text-processing-pipeline/ - there is some home that a future version of sphinx may be able to handle it.